# React : make div take all available height

Tags: css, reactjs, height

I'm struggling to make my div take all available height.

Here's my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/htstranslator-n3p04
The issue is when the search founds no cards.

I tried flex, flex-grow, etc and nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it as: `min-heigh: 100vh;` it should take it

### Edit:

So this is a little bit more complex than what it look based on your html structure, I would recommand css as follow:

```css
body, #root, .content{
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Then where you are having `<div class="h-100"` make it like:

```html
<div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: 100vh;">
```

With all this setting it should like:
[image]

Comment: The size is changing with that property but I changed the title, I made a mistake.

Comment: @AnthonyDa Did you try `flex:1 1 auto;` or `flex-shrink: auto;` ??

Comment: I tried flex: 1 1 auto; and flex-grow : 1 but not flex-shrink

Comment: @AnthonyDa so based on what you are telling me, I understand that you are trying to make the div `cardsContent` bigger than the other. But as it is now it does not seem bad. Or which div are you talking about ? As you just mentionned "_make my div take all available height._" but as your whole structure is with div, it is hard to tell which...

Comment: Yep, it's this one, when there are cards the size is good but it's when there are no cards that I want the div to take all the available space. Try to search for a card that does not exist.

Comment: @AnthonyDa I edited my answer, it should work fine with all this modification. As I checked it on the image